# High frequency tone/ringing in movies/music and its effects

Tags: neurology, hearing, psychology

I was watching a horror movie and I noticed during a scene that there was a high pitched noise playing in the background. It had been playing for a while before I noticed it and when I took notice it started to irritate my ears, however this isn't my concern. I noticed that while this noise played during the scene I was in a trance-like state almost felt like I was hypnotized, so my question is can these high pitched sounds be used put the viewer/listener into a trance-like state or hypnotize them and if so are there any scientific studies that prove or debunk my theory?

Comment: Firstly, my diagnosis: "nocebo effect". Secondly, this is probably entering the psychology/social sciences(/economics?) domain... See if this video hurts too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2hO4_UEe-4

Comment: Thank you for your input i didnt think id ever get any answers

Comment: Noo don't think like that! I am not saying you will not get any answers, I am saying, that if you modify the tags, it will very much likely ***boost*** your chances of getting those answers :). We need people like you, and the correct Stack Exchange site: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/, or the correct tags will open your question up to different experts (see: @NormalHuman, believes in your question too).

Comment: I understand what you meant. I just didnt expect to get a reply since i posted this well over a month ago

Comment: Still I dont think it was a nocebo effect as I didnt feel I was in harms way at any point. It was more like i was being forced or tricked into focusing on what was on the screen the sound drew my in and before I knew it I was as i said earlier in a trance like state I was just kinda blank if that makes sense?

Comment: Hmm, I honestly do not know, as in I think I am not the expert here? Let's grab some popcorn and see who answers it fastest :)

Comment: I find that certain music puts me in a state where I fall out of consciousness and everthing around me just doesnt exist for a time so i wanted to know if this is something that can be intentionally induced through sound

Comment: Thanks for replying atleast this is something that is very intriguing to me as I would like to utilise this if a technique exists